# Powershell "if more than one, then delete all but one"

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to do something like this in Powershell:

"If more than one file includes a certain set of text, delete all but one"

Example:

- "...Cam1....jpg"
- "...Cam2....jpg"
- "...Cam2....jpg"
- "...Cam3....jpg"

Then I would want one of the two "...Cam2....jpg" deleted, while the other one should stay.

I know that I can use something like

```
gci *Cam2* | del
```

but I don't know how I can make one of these files stay.

Also, for this to work, I need to look through all the files to see if there are any duplicates, which defeats the purpose of automating this process with a Powershell script.

I searched for a solution to this for a long time, but I just can't find something that is applicable to my scenario.

Comment: You could do something like group the files with [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.1), take any groups with a `Count` of more than 1, use [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1) to skip over the first item and then delete the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a list of files into a collection and use [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#:%7E:text=Range%20operator%20..,an%20upper%2C%20and%20lower%20boundary.&text=You%20can%20also%20create%20ranges%20in%20reverse%20order.&text=Beginning%20in%20PowerShell%206%2C%20the,the%20boundary%20characters%20in%20quotes.) to select a subset of its elements. To remove all but first element, start from index one. Like so,

```
$cams = gci "*cam2*"
if($cams.Count -gt 1) {
    $cams[1..$cams.Count] | remove-item
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the idea of commenter [boxdog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9529842/boxdog):

```
# Find all duplicately named files.
$dupes = Get-ChildItem c:\test -file -recurse | Group-Object Name | Where-Object Count -gt 1

# Delete all duplicates except the 1st one per group.
$dupes | ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Remove-Item -Force }
```

I've split this up into two sub tasks to make it easier to understand. Also it is a good idea to always separate directory iteration from file deletion, to avoid inconsistent results.

First statement uses `Group-Object` to group files by names. It outputs a `Count` property containing the number of files per group. Then `Where-Object` is used to get only groups that contain more than one file, which will be the dupes. The result is stored in variable `$dupes`, which is an array that looks like this:

```
Count Name        Group
----- ----        -----
    2 file1.txt   {C:\test\subdir1\file1.txt, C:\test\subdir2\file1.txt}
    2 file2.txt   {C:\test\subdir1\file2.txt, C:\test\subdir2\file2.txt}
```

The second statement uses `ForEach-Object` to iterate over all groups of duplicates. From the `Group-Object` call of the 1st statement we got a `Group` property that contains an array of file informations. Using `Select-Object -Skip 1` we select all but the 1st element of this array, which are passed to `Remove-Item` to delete the files.